# Is it always possible to characterize the inverse of $f(X)$ if both $f$ and $X$ are characterizable?

Tags: logic

This is a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884453/when-is-it-possible-to-find-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-linking-two-conc?rq=1). I am trying to formalize an intuitive notion/question: **Is it always possible to write down necessary and sufficient conditions (i.e. formulas) for a property $P$?**

Let $\mathcal {Y,X}$ be two arbitrary sets, and $f:\mathcal X\to\mathcal Y$ some function.

Let $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X}$ be a language in first order logic over some set $\mathcal X$, i.e. containing propositional formulae and quantifiers **only over $\mathcal X$**. A set $X\subseteq\mathcal {X}$ is called "**characterizable in $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X}$**" if we can write down an $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X}$-formula $\phi_X(x)$ such that $\phi_X(x)$ is true iff $x\in X$. Similarly for $Y\subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ if there is such a formula $\phi_Y(y)$ in a language $\mathcal L_{\mathcal Y}$.

A function $f$ is called "**characterizable**" if we can write down an $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X, \mathcal Y}$-formula $\phi_f(x,y)$ such that $\phi_f(x,y)$ is true iff $f(x)=y$.

> **Conjecture**. If a set $Y\subseteq \mathcal Y$ is characterizable in some $\mathcal L_{\mathcal Y}$, and $f:\mathcal X\to\mathcal Y$ is characterizable in some $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X, \mathcal Y}$, then $X=f^{-1}(Y)$ is characterizable in some language $\mathcal L_{\mathcal X}$.

- **Does this formalism capture the desired intuition well? (that we can always write down "necessary and sufficient conditions").**
- **Does this definition of "characterizable" already exist?**
- **Is this conjecture correct?**

Comment: Comment in response to the edit: Can you clarify what you mean by $\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}}$? Can you give an example of an interesting characterizable function between two explicit structures $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$?

Comment: I ask because the usual setting for the notion of definable function is that $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are sorts or definable subsets within a single $\mathcal{L}$-structure. If instead they are separate structures with no primitive relations between them, there will be very few definable functions between them (essentially just piecewise constant functions with finitely many pieces).

Comment: Also: in the edited version of the conjecture, I don't think you mean the conclusion to be that $X$ is characterizable in *some* language $\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{X}}$. Indeed, every set is characterizable in *some* language, namely the language that includes a relation symbol picking out that set. Instead, you have some fixed language for $\mathcal{X}$ in mind from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the definition already exists. In logic, we use the word **definable** (e.g. definable set, definable function) to mean exactly this.

The answer to your conjecture depends on what logical framework you're working in (what counts as a formula?). But in first-order logic, for example, the answer is yes. If $Y\subseteq \mathcal{Y}$ is defined by $\varphi_Y(y)$ and $f\colon \mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}$ is defined by $\varphi_f(x,y)$, then $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ is defined by $\exists y\, (\varphi_f(x,y)\land \varphi_Y(y))$.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this clarifies. Now that you gave the definition of $X$, I noticed that I really wanted to put a stronger requirement on what it means for $X$ to be “characterizable”. What I really mean is, that it is definable using formula’s in a language that is only allows to refer to elements in $\mathcal X$. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

For characterizable $X\subseteq{\cal X}$ think about the characteristic function of $X$ in the universe $\cal X$, i.e.,
$$\chi_X = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{if } x\in X\\0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
For characterizable $f:{\cal X}\rightarrow{\cal Y}$ just consider the graph of the function, i.e.,
$$R_f = \{(x,f(x))\mid x\in{\cal X}\}.$$

Comment: I would say that these don't count because e.g. $\chi_X$ is using the symbol for $X$ even though $X$ is not defined (it is supposed to be the job of $\chi_X$ to do that). In other words, this formula $\chi$ doesn't pin down a particular such set $X$.

Comment: This answer seems to be describing a way of assigning a definable function to each definable set and vice-versa. This is sometimes a useful thing to do, but I don't see any connection to the actual question.