# Getting rid of quantifiers over functions

Tags: functions, logic

This is a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935395/is-it-always-possible-to-characterize-the-inverse-of-fx-if-both-f-and-x?noredirect=1#comment6066277_2935395), and I'm in general trying to better understand under what conditions it is possible to find simplified equivalent formula's for a complex formula. It is possible to prove the equivalence between the following two formulas (using the axiom of choice):

$$\begin{align}
&\text {some sets }A,B\\
&\forall f:A\to B, [\forall a,P(a,f(a)) \to \forall a,Q(a,f(a))]\tag 1&\\
&\forall a\forall b,[P(a,b)\to Q(a,b)]&\quad \text {where}\tag 2\\
&P:A\times B \to \{T,F\}\\
&Q:A\times B \to \{T,F\}
\end{align}$$

**Essentially, the first equation quantifies over functions, but we can use the axiom of choice to get rid of quantification over $f$**, and talk only directly about $a$'s and $b's$. This is nice because functions are "unnecessarily complicated" in this case, so the second formula is much simpler.

**I am trying to understand when it is and when it is not possible to remove quantifiers over functions like this.**
Obviously, it would not be possible for the following formula:

$$\forall f:A\to B, [\forall a,\tilde P(a,f) \to \forall a,\tilde Q(a,f)]$$
If $\tilde P(a,f)$ and $\tilde Q(a,f)$ are arbitrary (i.e. we know nothing about them). However, I'm not so sure if it's still impossible for a proposition like the following:

$$\begin{align}
&\forall f,g:A\to B,[ \{\forall a,P(a,r(f,g)) \}\to\{\forall a,Q(a,r(f,g)))\}]\tag 3\\
&r:(A\to B)\times (A\to B)\to B
\end{align}$$

Where we instead know *everything* about $r$, i.e. we know the exact function $r$. In this case, it seems like we should be able to use this complete information about $r$ to "triangulate" and get rid of the quantifiers over $A\to B $. But I'm not sure, and don't know how to find out. (Maybe it is possible for some $r$ and not others, or iff $r$ is computable, or something like that).

I am similarly unsure for a formula like this:

### $$\begin{align}
&\forall f:A\to B,[ \{\forall a,\bar P(r(f,k(a))) \}\to\{\forall a, \bar Q(r(f,k( a)))\}]\tag 4\\
&r:(A\to B)\times (A\to B)\to B\\
&k:A\to (A\to B)\\
&\bar P,\bar Q:B\to \{T,F\}
\end{align}$$

**So I have two questions:**

**Question 1.** Is there an example of a formula of form $(3)$ or $(4)$ or similar (with quantifiers over functions, and complete information of how those functions reduce to properties over the underlying sets), where we provably cannot reduce it to a formula without quantifiers over functions?

**Question 2.** Is there a topic in math/logic that I can look at that would clarify this for me? (i.e. the problem of turning formula's containing quantifiers over $A\to B$ into one containing only quantifiers over $A$ and $B$). Is there a generally accepted name for this problem/topic, or something related?

**Edit:** It seems to me that the trick that @MeesdeVries did, cannot be applied to this formula:

$$\forall f:A\to B,\exists \bar a, \{\forall a, P(\bar a, r(f,k(a))) \}\to\{\forall a,  Q(\bar a, r(f,k( a)))\}]\tag 5$$

Comment: not sure why the last set of equations is bigger than the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your (3) is equivalent to
$$
\forall b \in \mathrm{im}(r)(\forall aP(a, b) \implies \forall aQ(a, b)), \tag{*}
$$
because if your (3) is true, then to prove my (*) for $b$ just choose $f, g$ with $r(f, g) = b$; while if your (3) is false, then if $f, g$ are functions that prove it false, $b = r(f, g)$ will prove my (*) false.

Of course, defining $\mathrm{im}(r)$ requires an existential quantifier over functions, and that might not actually be better as far as you're concerned.

Your second question is almost impossible to answer without specifying it down a little bit, but you might be interested in the study of *quantifier complexity* (which surprisingly does not have a Wikipedia page, although you can look at the [page for the arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)).

Comment: "Of course, defining $\text {im}(r)$ requires an existential quantifier over functions, and that might not actually be better as far as you're concerned." In this case, I am ok with it, since at least if $r$ is a total function (a light assumption) then we can turn it into $\forall b\in B$. In general, for any particular $r$ we may be able to characterize $\text {im}(r)$ explicitly, without quantifiers. Is there always a way to turn a formula with quantifiers over functions into a formula with *bounded* quantifiers over underlying sets like this?

Comment: Also, do you know of a good introduction to quantifier complexity, and/or related topics? I've been looking online a bit but can't find anything that's clearly good.

Comment: @Programmer2134, no, not really. If you want to read more about that specific subject I would recommend asking another question.