# How to simplify this statement?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $P$ be a finite set of vectors in $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^n$ with $1$-norm of $1$. i.e. for each $p\in P$, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^np_i = 1$.

I have the following statement:

> A particular such set $P$ satisfies the property $\phi(P)$ iff: For every pair of two arbitrary vectors $d,e\in\mathbb R^n$, if ($d_1>d_2$ and $e_1\leq e_2$), or ($d_2>d_1$ and $e_2\leq e_1$), then there exists two $p,q\in P$ such that
>
> - $d\cdot q>d\cdot p$, and
> - For all $r\in P$, it holds that $e\cdot r\leq e\cdot p$

**I am looking for a simplified statement of $\phi(P)$, that doesn't include a reference to the vectors $d,e$.** i.e. a statement that is equivalent to it (assuming that $P$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^n$ with $1$-norm $1$), but simplified in that way.

I've been looking for a simplified form for a while now, but can't find it.

I have two questions:

**My main question: A methodological question**. I am looking for a way to prove or at least make a good educated guess whether such a simplified statement even theoretically exists. Is there a principle by which we can reason that the statement can or cannot possibly be simplified in that way? (I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940557/getting-rid-of-quantifiers-over-functions) about this), also see [this question for a motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884453/when-is-it-possible-to-find-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-linking-two-conc?rq=1).

**A practical question.** If it is possible, how do we actually go about simplifying it?

Comment: It seems like an odd condition: you are using $n$-dimensional vectors, but part of the condition only refers to the first and second coordinates of $d$ and $e$?

Comment: @Joppy, yes that's correct. This makes it hard to simplify it seems. (and that's also one of the reasons I want to get rid of the $d,e$ stuff altogether, if possible). Basically the subcondition is: if one of the first two elements of the first vector is strictly bigger than the other, but this doesn't hold for the other vector.

Comment: That condition is precisely the fact that $d$ and $e$ have opposite (or zero, for $e$) signs when dotted with $(1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$, but I'm not sure if that fact can be used to simplify the statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to present your condition in a point-free way:

1. Let $R(a,b)$ be a relation on vectors defined by the condition $(a_1-a_2)(b_1-b_2) > 0$ or $(b_1-b_2) = 0$.
2. For each $p\in P$, let $A_p \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the set of vectors for which $p$ gives a maximal dot product relative to any other $q\in P$:

   $$A_p \equiv \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \forall q \in P,  (x\cdot p \geq x\cdot q) \}.$$

   Interestingly, the sets $A_p$ are not necessarily disjoint (maxima are not necessarily unique), and they are closed under positive linear combinations.
3. Let $S_P(a,b)$ be another relation on vectors defined by $\forall p \in P, (a \in A_p \Rightarrow b\in A_p).$
4. Then your condition $\phi(P)$ is equivalent to the condition that $P$ is nonempty and that $S_P\subseteq R$.

$\square$

---

*Proof:*

- Abstractly, your condition reads: $\phi(P)$ holds iff for every pair of vectors $d$ and $e$, the condition $f(\ldots)$ implies that there exist $p,q\in P$ for which $g(\ldots)$ and $h(\ldots)$.
- Filling in arguments, $\phi(P)$ holds iff for every pair of vectors $d$ and $e$, the condition $f(d,e)$ implies that there exist $p,q\in P$ for which $g(d,p,q)$ and $h(e,p)$.
- The condition $h(e,p)$ is just that $p$ maximizes the dot product with $e$. As long as $P$ is nonempty, $h(e,p)$ will always be satisfied— some $p$ maximizes the dot product. So we don't have to worry about the existence of $p$ satisfying $h(e,p)$ as long as $P$ is nonempty.
- The notation $A_p$ actually makes these two conditions simpler. The condition $h(e,p)$ is just $e \in A_p$. The condition that there exists $q$ such that $g(d,p,q)$ is just $d \notin A_p$ (!).
- So, we can rewrite your condition as:

  > ... if $P$ is nonempty, then for every pair $d, e$, the condition $f(d,e)$ implies that there's a $p$ for which $(e\in A_p)$ and $(d \notin A_p)$.

  A great simplification, given that we've now eliminated reference to $q$.
- Using contrapositive, we can equivalently write:

  > ... if $P$ is nonempty, then for every pair $d, e$, the condition $\forall p\in P, [(e\notin A_p)$ or $(d \in A_p)]$ implies that $f(d,e)$ fails.

  or just

  > ... if $P$ is nonempty, then for every pair $d, e$, the condition $\forall p\in P, [(e\in A_p)\Rightarrow (d \in A_p)]$ implies that $f(d,e)$ fails.
- Let $S_P(a,b)$ be this first condition, which does depend on $P$. Let $R(a,b)$ be the second condition (the failure of $f$), which does not.
- We can use arithmetic to define $R$ succinctly, and we can replace implication with set inclusion for further brevity.

We find that $\phi(P)$ is equivalent to the condition that $P$ is nonempty and that $S_P\subseteq R$.

Comment: This is not a solution. If you expand your condition $S_P\subseteq R$ into a first-order statement, you just get forall $d,e\in \mathbb R^n$, .... In fact, it seems like your condition is just restating my condition into set-relations. It doesn't actually simplify it, it just "hides" the complexity into the definitions of $S_P$, $A_p$, and $R$. I am looking for a statement that is actually simpler than the beginning one, and more importantly, an understanding of why this is or is not even theoretically possible.