# Introduction to quantifier complexity

Tags: logic, reference-request, quantifiers

I am looking for a good introductory text to the theory of quantifier complexity. It can be a chapter in a larger text on logic. I have an understanding of logic already.

Everything I could find online was either advanced, or only a few slides in a powerpoint presentation.

This question is motivated by [this answer to an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2940568/360475). I am interested in simplifying formulae, specifically in getting rid of quantifiers over functions $A\to B$, but also more generally in understanding when formulae can and cannot be reduced to simpler ones (e.g. see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936517/how-to-simplify-this-statement)). e.g. I am interested in the arithmetic hierarchy (though I'm not sure how well it captures the specific case where there are quantifiers like $f:A\to A$, which I think would require a multi-sorted theory?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the theory of quantifier complexity?" Do you have a specific context in mind (e.g. [the arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy))?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I am interested in the arithmetical hierarchy yes, and would be interested in something that addresses that. (but the question is motivated by something specific, namely what I referenced in the other question).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I'm not sure where I should look if I want to learn about the arithmetical hierarchy (beyond what's on the wikipedia page) do you have a suggestion?